# Is it possible to gain Tab Focus of a JTable Header Cell?

Tags: java, swing, header, tabs, jtable

I have a JTable that has a table header which contains a JPanel with a JLabel with a mouse listener on the JLabel.  When the JLabel is clicked a dialog is shown.  I'm trying to trigger this JLabel in the JTable heading without a mouse.  In order to trigger this JLabel without a mouse, I need the focus to be on the JTable heading (that is, I need the JTable heading to be in the focus traversal policy). Does anybody know if its possible to Tab to a JTable heading cell?

Answer (score 2):

```
table.getTableHeader().setFocusable(true)
```

alternatively, you might add the action "triggered by the JLabel" to the table's action map and bind it to a keyStroke in the table's when_ancestor inputMap

Answer (score 2):

Focus can be placed on the TableHeader by using `F8` when focus is on the table.

You can then use the right/left keys to move between the header cells.

You use the Tab key to place focus back on the table.